# How can i make buttons on a HTML page show different information

Tags: javascript, html

i am making an information website for a school assignment, i want to have a button/s to make different information display on the page. how do i go about doing this in HTML or other applicable languages, Thanks

Comment: I hope it will be helpful to you.
http://jsfiddle.net/e2jjkb8u/

Comment: @lv0gun9 you might be psychic because I would have never gotten that out of this question

Comment: @Jhecht I'm not good at English, I felt it is broad question. so I answered very simple and partial way.

Comment: @lv0gun9 How would i impliment this for 5 ect pieces of text?

Comment: @EllisRourke check this. http://jsfiddle.net/qmL5kpsL/ And do you have any experience about web programming or write HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JavaScript!

```
<body>
    <input id="button1" type="button" value="click me">
    <input id="button2" type="button" value="click me, too">
    <p id="output"></p>

    <script>
        /* Get references to your elements. */
        var button1=document.getElementById("button1");
        var button2=document.getElementById("button2");
        var output=document.getElementById("output");

        /* Add click event listeners to your buttons so you can interact with them. */
        button1.addEventListener("click",clickButton1);
        button2.addEventListener("click",clickButton2);

        /* Write functions to handle displaying various content depending on which button you press. */
        function clickButton1(event_){
            output.innerHTML="You clicked button1!";
        }

        function clickButton2(event_){
            output.innerHTML="You clicked button2!";
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Basically, your click event listeners handle what to display when a button is pressed. I'm just changing the text in a p element, but you could do a lot more than that. For example, store the different html you want to display in hidden divs and only display them when a button is pressed. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do this in CSS as well, the big thing to note in the example is that each `<a>` has the `#(id of div)` in the href attribute. Since I don't know the exact context for your predicament, I can't say this would work how you want it to, but I just really dislike using javascript if I don't have to.

```css
.container > div {
  display: none
}
.container > div:target {
  display: block;
}
ul.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
ul li button {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  box-sizing: padding-box;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <button><a href="#firstTab">Tab 1</a>
    </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button><a href="#secondTab">Tab 2</a>
    </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button><a href="#thirdTab">Tab 3</a>
    </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button><a href="#fourthTab">Tab 4</a>
    </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button><a href="#fifthTab">Tab 5</a>
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="container">
  <div id="firstTab">Hello Tab 1</div>
  <div id="secondTab">Hello Tab 2</div>
  <div id="thirdTab">Hello Tab 3</div>
  <div id="fourthTab">Hello Tab 4</div>
  <div id="fifthTab">Hello Fifth Tab</div>
</div>
```